# Ошибка в консоли Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript

Что означает ошибка **Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined**?

[image: error]

Вот код **js**, делал анимацию для "бургер меню"

```
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement(element + '.hamburger').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    selectElement(element + '.hamburger').classList.toggle(token + 'active');
    selectElement(element + '.nav-list').classList.toggle(token + 'active');
});
```

А это пример, какая должна быть анимация, но из-за ошибок ничего не получается...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfNu7R5Sq0M

Вот HTML и CSS коды:
https://codepen.io/nomnom_x/pen/KKVypNN?editors=0010

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Comment: `selectElement(element + '.hamburger')` - где ты определяешь переменную `element`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(вместо видео, хорошо бы вставить скрин нужного кадра в вопрос, если это необходимо).

На видео человек использует редактор, который при написании функции добавляет подсказку - какой параметр там должен быть. `selectElement(element: '.hamburger')` часть "element:" - подсказка редактора, которая не выполняется как код.

А у вас `element + '.hamburger'` JS пытается найти переменную element и приклеить её к строке '.hamburger'. Не находит переменную - выдает ошибку.

```
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.hamburger').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    selectElement('.hamburger').classList.toggle(token + 'active');
    selectElement('.nav-list').classList.toggle(token + 'active');
});
```

Comment: спасибо вам, очень помогли! Ой, не заметил, что дело в подсказке функции...